# Unit testing django inline formsets

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

In attempting to programmatically post a new ForeignKey object through an inline formset, I'm receiving an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`.

Here's the code of my test (bloated for the sake of brevity here):

```
def test_merits_can_be_added(self):
    self.c = Client()
    self.c.login(username=self.user.username, password='dummy')
    self.post_data = {
      'name':u'Unhappy SE',
      'concept':u'Sad clown',
      'merit-TOTAL_FORMS':u'1',
      'merit-MAX_NUM_FORMS':u'',
      'merit-INITIAL_FORMS':u'1',
      'merit-0-id':u'',
      'merit-0-level':u'2',
      'merit-0-character':u'1',
      'merit-0-trait':u'11',
      'merit-0-specializations':u'Sometimes'
    }
    sheet = GeistCharacterSheet.objects.create(name='Happy SE', user=self.user)
    response = self.c.post(sheet.get_absolute_url(), self.post_data, follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(GeistCharacterSheet.objects.get(pk=1).chosentrait_set.all().filter(trait__name='Common Sense')[0].level, 2)
    self.assertEqual(GeistCharacterSheet.objects.get(pk=1).chosentrait_set.all().filter(trait__name='Common Sense')[0].specializations, u'Sometimes')
```

The view code (again, trimmed for brevity):

```
def character_sheet(request, sheet_id=None):
  charsheet = GeistCharacterSheet.objects.get(pk=sheet_id, user=request.user)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    sheet_form = GeistCharacterSheetForm(request.POST, instance=charsheet)          
    merit_formset = setup_merit_form(charsheet, post=request.POST)

    if sheet_form.is_valid() and merit_formset.is_valid():
      sheet_form.save()
      merit_formset.save()
      return redirect('/character-manager/list/')

def setup_merit_form(charsheet, post=None):
  MeritFormSet = inlineformset_factory(GeistCharacterSheet, ChosenTrait, form=ChosenMeritForm, extra=1)
  if post:
    return MeritFormSet(post, instance=charsheet, queryset=ChosenTrait.objects.filter(trait__trait_type__name='Merit'), prefix='merit')
  else:
    return MeritFormSet(instance=charsheet, queryset=ChosenTrait.objects.filter(trait__trait_type__name='Merit'), prefix='merit')
```

Here's the traceback from the test execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\charon_sheet\..\charon_sheet\character_manager\tests.py", line 119, in test_skills_can_be_changed
    response = self.c.post(sheet.get_absolute_url(), self.post_data, follow=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\test\client.py", line 449, in post
    response = super(Client, self).post(path, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\test\client.py", line 259, in post
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\charon_sheet\..\charon_sheet\character_manager\views.py", line 29, in character_sheet
    merit_formset = setup_merit_form(charsheet, post=request.POST)
  File "C:\charon_sheet\..\charon_sheet\character_manager\views.py", line 69, in setup_merit_form
    return MeritFormSet(post, instance=charsheet, queryset=ChosenTrait.objects.filter(trait__trait_type__name='Merit'), prefix='merit')
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\models.py", line 682, in __init__
    queryset=qs)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\models.py", line 415, in __init__
    super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\formsets.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._construct_forms()
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\formsets.py", line 108, in _construct_forms
    self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i))
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\models.py", line 691, in _construct_form
    form = super(BaseInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\forms\models.py", line 437, in _construct_form
    connection=connections[self.get_queryset().db])
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\fields\subclassing.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\fields\subclassing.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 306, in get_db_prep_lookup
    value = self.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 292, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 479, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I can post models, forms, more of the view, whatever anyone thinks would be helpful.

The issue is with the `'merit-0-id':u''` post item. I've tried with and without unicode, using 0 or -1, using `False`, using `'new'` (a complete wild shot, I know).

My major confusion comes in that the form works when I'm running the server. I've examined the POST variables when I submit the form, and that id field can be empty and the item is added just fine.

Why is the form balking when it's submitted via a test runner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initial forms in an inline formset need to tie back to existing models in the DB. Your setup doesn't create the related `ChosenTrait` instance (which is the pk you should be using for `merit-0-id`). If you are testing creating all new models then `'merit-INITIAL_FORMS'` should be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

An empty field isn't the same as one with an empty string.

If a field is empty, the browser doesn't include it in the query string at all. However, you've simulated a POST with that field containing an empty string, which confuses things. Remove that key altogether from the dict.

Comment: Yup, I wondered about that. Unfortunately, if I remove it, I get a MultiValueDictKeyError, because it's looking for the 'merit-0-id' field in the dict.